# How to get Parcel to compile a Phaser game with 'classProperties'?

Tags: phaser-framework, parceljs

I completed a Phaser game tutorial that ran fine when linking to the Phaser.js library on the Web using:
`<script    src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.50.1/dist/phaser.js"></script>`

But now when I try to use Phaser locally with npm, and Parcel to run the game I get the compile error:
`@parcel/transformer-js: This experimental syntax requires enabling the parser plugin: 'classProperties'`

Which is caused by this type of code:

```js
export default class Game extends Phaser.Scene
{
    /** @type {Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite} */
    player;
```

I can't find anything on Google, except someone said to add the plugin to my package.json file, so now I have:

```json
"dependencies": 
{
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
    "parcel": "^2.0.0-nightly.548",
    "phaser": "^3.53.1"
}
```

What else can I do to try fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `.babelrc` file in the root of your project containing the following code:

```json
{
    "plugins": 
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
}
```

Source: https://robkendal.co.uk/blog/2019-05-13-configure-parcel-js-and-babel-to-use-javascript-proposal-class-properties